# Error while calculating index value from props React (works when hardcoded)

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am using this to create a 3D interactive view for a product: https://github.com/aldrinc/React360. The code in question is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./React360.css";

// You can play with this to adjust the sensitivity
// higher values make mouse less sensitive
const pixelsPerDegree = 3;

class React360 extends Component {
static defaultProps = { dir: 'awair-360', numImages: 55 };

  state = {
    dragging: false,
    imageIndex: 0,
    dragStartIndex: 0
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove, false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.handleMouseUp, false);
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.handleMouseUp, false);
  };

  handleMouseDown = e => {
    e.persist();
    this.setState(state => ({
      dragging: true,
      dragStart: e.screenX,
      dragStartIndex: state.imageIndex
    }));
  };

  handleMouseUp = () => {
    this.setState({ dragging: false });
  };

  updateImageIndex = currentPosition => {
    let numImages = this.props.numImages;
    const pixelsPerImage = pixelsPerDegree * (360 / numImages);
    const { dragStart, imageIndex, dragStartIndex } = this.state;
    // pixels moved
    let dx = (currentPosition - dragStart) / pixelsPerImage;
    let index = Math.floor(dx) % numImages;

    if (index < 0) {
      index = numImages + index - 1;
    }
    index = (index + dragStartIndex) % numImages;
    // console.log(index, dragStartIndex, numImages)
    if (index !== imageIndex) {
      this.setState({ imageIndex: index });
    }
  };

  handleMouseMove = e => {
    if (this.state.dragging) {
      this.updateImageIndex(e.screenX);
    }
  };

  preventDragHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  renderImage = () => {
    const { imageIndex } = this.state;

    if (isNaN(imageIndex)) {
        this.setState({imageIndex: 0})
        return
    }

    return (
      <div className="react360">

        <img
          className="react-360-img"
          alt=""
          src={require(`./${this.props.dir}/${imageIndex}.jpg`)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div
        className="react-360-img"
        onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
        onDragStart={this.preventDragHandler}
      >
        {this.renderImage()}
      </div>
    );
  };
}


export default React360;
```

I am running into an issue where hardcoding the variable for the number of images (numImages) results in proper function but when I set the number of images as a prop `let numImages = this.props.numImages;` my image index sometimes goes to NaN. I've made a hacky workaround by setting the imageIndex state to 0 if it is NaN but I would like to resolve this issue correctly by understanding what exactly is different with setting a variable using props vs hardcoding.

Comment: Are you saying that "index" sometimes goes to NaN - if that is the case, index is dependent on more than just numImages; I see it depends on "Math.floor(dx) % numImages" - at that statement, please log both dx and numImages. Is numImages NaN or not?

Comment: numImages might be undefined at the time of calling React360 component and passing numImages as props to it. So before passing numImages to React360 check whether numImages has value and only then pass to it as props like {this.state.numImages && this.state.numImages != undefined && <React360 numImages={this.state.numImages} />

Comment: @ChrisCousins Interestingly enough when I log numImages its always 55 but the index value only goes to NaN when numImages is retrieved from props and not when hardcoded.

Comment: @Think-Twice I will try it

Comment: Ah I see, although you have set defaultProps of numImages to 55, that will only happen if the parent class hasn't passed in numImages to the component; in which case that would override your defaults. If it is passed as undefined, then your defaults would be fine, however if it is passed as null, then that would override your defaults.

Comment: @ChrisCousins Hmm that does make sense but I am passing it like so         `<React360 dir="awair-360" numImages="55" />`

Comment: hm I see in your defaultProps numImages is a number, but when you pass it from the parent it is a string... Can you try <React360 dir="awair-360" numImages={55} /> ?

Comment: @ChrisCousins that fixed it :O